# MySQL: How can I remove trailing HTML from a field in the database?

Tags: sql, mysql, string

I want to remove some rogue HTML from a DB field that is supposed to contain a simple filename. Example of ok field:

```
myfile.pdf
```

Example of not ok field:

```
myfile2.pdf<input type="hidden" id="gwProxy" />...
```

Does anyone know a query I can run that can remove the HTML part but leave the filename? i.e. remove everything from the first `<` character onwards.

Lets assume the field is called `myattachment` and is defined as a `varchar(250)` and the table is called `mytable` in a MySQL database.

---

Background info (*not necessary to read*):

The field in our database is supposed to contain filenames however, due to a issue ([documented here](http://github.com/valums/ajax-upload/issues/issue/71)) some of the fields now contain a filename **and some rogue HTML**. We have fixed the root issue and now need to fix the corrupt fields. In the past I have replaced text using this kind of query:

```
UPDATE mytable SET myattachment = replace(myattachment, 'JPG', 'jpg') WHERE myattachment LIKE '%JPG';
```

Comment: How many rows does the table have?  If not over 1million I suggest extracting the id and myattachment to a file.  Use a text editor with regular expression to do the replace and import back the column.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I did consider fixing the issue using a PHP script to read the rows, fix the corruption and write them back. But then I thought there must be a MySQL query I can run that will be quicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query seems to work ok, can anyone see any issues with it?

```
UPDATE mytable
   SET myattachment = SUBSTRING_INDEX(myattachment, '<', 1) 
 WHERE `myattachment` LIKE '%<%';
```

For docs on `SUBSTRING_INDEX` see the [mysql manual page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index).